# XSL Two Conditions Expression If Test

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I can get my 2 expressions to process as I want with:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(.) > 15">
    <xsl:if test="not(contains(., ' '))">
        <xsl:attribute name="font-size">5pt</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
```

however I'm not clear why I can't just write it as one `test`:

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(.) > 15 && not(contains(., ' '))">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">5pt</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

this throws back an unknown error with my processor (Apache XSL FO).

I'm trying to test the current node I'm in to see if it contains more than 15 characters and no white space. If that match is met I reduce the font size to `5pt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression language used in XSLT is XPath, in XSLT 2.0 it is XPath 2.0. The boolean `and` operator just has the English name so `string-length(.) > 15 and not(contains(., ' '))` is all you need.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks. Is this documented here, https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/ or where can I read more about this?

Comment: The XSLT 1 spec in https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#section-Expressions links to the XPath 1 spec https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/, the XSLT 2 spec to the XPath 2 spec https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/. Any XSLT and/or XPath tutorial might of course be a lighter read than the formal and detailed specs. XSLT processor/tool companies like Saxonica or Altova also offer detailed documentation like http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/expressions/ or https://www.altova.com/training-tutorials.